# Sorting on full text columns in sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I know you can sort by integer values in sphinx but is there a way I can get sphinx to sort by a text field alphabetically?

I want to search on first name and instead of sorting on relevance, I'd like to sort by the first name alphabetically.  I know I can do this in mysql but in mysql I don't have features like stemming (as far as I know).

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use strings as [ordinal attributes](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-attr-str2ordinal) - Sphinx will collect all values of the given column, sort them alphabetically, then give the first one a value of 1, the second a value of 2, and so forth. This allows for sorting, but not filtering.

Comment: Fantastic.  I'll give that a go.

Comment: I noticed that this isn't case insensitive.  E.g. AOL will come before America.

Comment: That's correct. You'll either want to create a cached column which stores all-downcase or all-uppercase versions of the original column, and then add that as an attribute; Or: use a MySQL/Postrgres function to transform the column on the fly in a SQL snippet for the attribute instead. Look at the end of the Fields section in the docs for a rather apt example. http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/indexing.html

Answer (score 2):

ordinal attribute  is  the easiet solution if you use a monolitic index.  If  you use a distributed index you have a problem.  but there is other solutions.

1° convert your string  in  numeric value. from sql with something like  conv(HEX(textfield),16,10)

hex is friendly with string  and return a concatened list of hexa values of chars)

2° with sphinx 2.0-x try  sql_string_field

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't sort by anything other than attributes (and a few special attributes like @weight, etc.).  Currently attributes cannot be strings, but this feature should be coming in 0.9.10 from what he's said about it.

http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sorting-modes